# How do I access Ubuntu after dual booting it alongside windows?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, uefi

I installed Ubuntu through a flash drive on my laptop with Windows 10. 
I partitioned ubuntu on an external hard drive.
I am not given an option to boot with Ubuntu when I start my computer, it just boots straight into Windows 10.

I found a similar question telling me to do the following:
change advanced startup options> restart now.>
Then after restarting, go to troubleshoot> advanced options> UEFI Firmware settings>

My problem so far is that I don't get the option UEFI Firmware settings after going to advanced options. 
I apologize if this is a dumb question I don't have a lot of knowledge in this area.

Comment: Can you plz a little bit better improve your question. Not everyone is good at english, it's hard to understand.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows